# How to hash *args **kwargs for function cache?

Tags: python

I'm working with `xlwt` which has a 4k limit on how many styles can be defined in an excel doc.

Normally, one creates styles like so:

```
style = xlwt.easyxf("font: bold 1")
```

Which I simply replaced with

```
def cached_easyxf(self, format):
    return self._cache.setdefault(format, xlwt.easyxf(format))
```

Which works perfectly. Now, I've found out that I need to pass in keyword arguments sometimes which got me thinking: how should I hash the args/kwargs signature?

Should I create a cache key based on str(value)? Pickle? What's most robust?

For my situation it looks like I can just convert key/values to strings and add it to my keys... but I'm now curious about a generic way to handle this with say unhashable types like `arg=[1, 2, 3]`

```
def cached_call(*args, **kwargs):
    return cache.get(what_here)
cached_call('hello')
cached_call([1, 2, 3], {'1': True})
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is the technique used in [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
kwd_mark = object()     # sentinel for separating args from kwargs

def cached_call(*args, **kwargs):
    key = args + (kwd_mark,) + tuple(sorted(kwargs.items()))
    return cache.get(key)
```

Note, the above code handles keyword arguments but makes no attempt to handle non-hashable values like lists. Your idea for using the `str` or a `list` is a reasonable start.  For `set` objects, you would need to sort the entries first, `str(sorted(someset))`.  Other objects may not have a useful `__repr__` or `__str__` (i.e. they may show only the object type and location in memory).  In summary, handling arbitrary unhashable arguments requires careful consideration of each object type.

Comment: Would the following work just as well: `key = (args, tuple(sorted(kwds.items())))`? Or is it slower because of inner tuples?

Comment: @max Yes, that would work.  And yes, the extra pointers would slow it down a bit as well as consuming a bit more memory.

Comment: Can also do `(args, frozenset(kwds.items()))`

Comment: @Raymond is kwds.items() suppose to be kwargs.items() ? I don't see kwds defined anywhere

Comment: With nested dictionaries, consider using `json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True)` to serialize dicts (whether in args or kwargs) - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22003440/484127)

Comment: @RaymondHettinger what is the best way to make custom lru_cache. If I will use for key representation from your example and result = f(*args, **kwargs). Then what to use, OrderedDict or Deque?

Comment: You need to map *args, **kwargs to some arbitrary function signature that you scrape via inspect.getfullargspec ... this is the generic pattern to cache a wrapped function. I think there are some corner cases missed by the above. Consider default arguments etc.