# Function to return the line number that the function is called

Tags: python, function

Is it possible to create a function in Python to detect and return the row number which the function is called?

For example, if the function is called at the line 32, the function returns 32.

I know that some libraries can do this, but I'd like to do it from scratch.

Comment: The built-in `inspect` module can do this.

Comment: What is the intended use case for this feature?

Comment: Why do you need this? See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438976/python-debugging-get-filename-and-line-number-from-which-a-function-is-called/24439444

Comment: @S3DEV Debugging and creating fun CTF puzzle maybe.

Comment: @jasonharper Thx!

Comment: @hpchavaz Thx! It helps.