# Prefix log messages with context-dependent data

Tags: python, logging, python-3.9

I want to prefix all the `log` entries inside one class by `self.instance_desc`. Like this:

```
logging.info(f"({self.instance_desc}) {message}")
```

But I don't want to write the prefix in each message.

How can I make it so it's automatic?

Already done:

I've added a new method to the class:

```
def log(message):
    logging.info(f"({self.instance_desc}) Message")
```

The problem is that `%(filename)s:%(lineno)d` is (obviously) pointing to the `log` method.

Is it possible to do this while `%(filename)s:%(lineno)d` pointing to the place where the `self.log` has been called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging: Get filename and line number from which a function is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438976/debugging-get-filename-and-line-number-from-which-a-function-is-called)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stacklevel` keyword parameter to logging calls to make the adjustment. This script:

```
import logging

def custom_log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['stacklevel'] = 3
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    logging.log(level, 'prefix: ' + msg, *args, **kwargs)

def baz():
    custom_log(logging.DEBUG, 'baz')

def bar():
    custom_log(logging.DEBUG, 'bar')
    baz()

def foo():
    custom_log(logging.DEBUG, 'foo')
    bar()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='line %(lineno)2d %(message)s')
foo()
```

should print

```
line 16 prefix: foo
line 12 prefix: bar
line  9 prefix: baz
```

In other words, it prints the location of the call to `custom_log()`. In my example it's a plain function rather than a method, but the principle's the same.

Comment: it's not clear how stacklevel helps. It is clear that in this class instead of calling the logging function directly you have added a custom_log function which adds the desired class instance information.

Comment: @JasonHarrison See the paragraphs in the question beginning "The problem is that ..." and "Is it possible to ,,," - that is what stacklevel is addressing.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the description of the stacklevel keyword argument and a reference to the documentation.