# Access lru_cache's cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, scope

**General problem**: How can I access a variable in a function's closure?

**Specific problem**: How can I access the raw `cache` from a python function wrapped with `functools.lru_cache()`?

If I memoize a function (example taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache))...

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

>>> [fib(n) for n in range(16)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]

>>> fib.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=28, misses=16, maxsize=None, currsize=16)
```

Here is where `cache` is defined: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f0851910eb8e711bf8f22165cb0df33bb27b09d6/Lib/functools.py#L491

When `fib()` is memoized, `lru_cache` adds a `cache_info()` and `cache_clear()` function to the wrapper.  `cache_clear()` has access to `cache` and I have access to `cache_clear()` so can I somehow use that to access `cache` directly?

Comment: It doesn't seem like something you should be able to do, it is a local variable in that function. The only hope you have is reflection. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: why? because I can.   really why? I want to persist cache between reboots while developing.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585493/store-the-cache-to-a-file-functools-lru-cache-in-python-3-2)?

Comment: While you *could* do this, with a lot of fragile poking at implementation details, it'd be better to just use your own memoization implementation.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/what-exactly-is-contained-within-a-obj-closure

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cachier`](https://github.com/shaypal5/cachier) by [Shay Palachy](https://github.com/shaypal5). You can tell it to cache to a [pickle file](https://github.com/shaypal5/cachier#pickle-core).

Alternatively, look at [`persistent_lru_cache`](https://github.com/abarnert/persistent-lru-cache/blob/master/persistent_lru_cache.py) developed by [Andrew Barnert](https://github.com/abarnert).