Function memoization, passing around precomputed values
I have a function like this in my library, which depends on a large subset of the inputs being pre-calculated:
@cache
def f(n, precompute):
    if n < len(precompute): 
        return precompute[n]

    # recursive calculations, which are memoized on return
    return some_compute(f(n-1, precompute))

What's the most user-friendly way to pass around a precomputed list while using memoizing functools.cache, without caching the precompute?
My ideas:

Just make precompute a global/outer scope variable (impure, global variable has to exist in the module beforehand How to create module-wide variables in Python?)
Make precompute a function attribute to use it as an "argument" bypassing caching (works because the function is an object)
Write a special memoziation decorator that is only based on the first argument (suggested in Caching Python function results using only subset of arguments as identifier)
Turn it into a class so precomputed can be an instance attribute or class attribute (this is what sympy.sieve does)
Load cache(f) with the values of precompute. My thinking is that this is less efficient as the cache will be a dictionary, while precompute is a simple list of size 10^7
Create an inner helper recursive function with one argument that uses precompute in the outer scope (I don't think works across multiple outer calls because the inner falls out of scope)


Is precompute somehow different from the cache? For example, if precompute[3] exists, is its value different from some_compute(f(2, precompute))? Are you just parametrizing the recursive function over possible base cases? (Like how the Fibonacci recurrence yields different sequences if you start with a different pair of numbers than 0 and 1.)

@chepner it's the same values, but precompute is a list/array generated via a different method, while I believe the cache is a dictionary with arguments as keys. Another idea is to insert all precomputed values into the cache internal dict, but this is less efficient than a flat list.

If it's the same values you can just use precompute to pre-populate the cache, and not make f explicitly dependent on it.

"nicest" -> opinion-based

How will the function get used? Always with the same precompute list or with different ones?

@nocomment same precompute list, calculated once. then f is called many times with different arguments for n.

And is it not in a global variable already anyway? Is it in some function's local variable? If so, is f outside of that function?

f is intended for a library. precompute can be a global/outer variable in the client code. in terms of efficiency in pypy, that's probably the fastest.

@chepner is it possible to pre-populate the cache outside of normal function calls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337329/access-lru-caches-cache

Why would you need to? Instead of the other function calls, just do something like for i in range(n): f(i). Or are you loading precomputed results from a file?

@chepner how would that make use of precompute list?

More specifically, precompute is generated via a (almost) linear time procedure, while f computes in sub-linear time (given the precompute)

If you’re asking how to use only one of the function arguments as a cache key, while using cache annotation, the answer is “you can’t”. You can create a dict and manually thread it around as the cache though. I always found this to be a glaring shortcoming in the cache annotation, and kinda stupid.

@AbhijitSarkar or if I can "preload" the cache with values, which I don't think I can

"global variable has to exist in the module beforehand" - Is that a problem? Or unexpected? Of course it has to exist before you use it. Just like with every other way...

@nocomment that's not necessarily true. Python could've been made so that an unbound variable keeps looking outwards in its calling scope, instead of globals being limited to their module. What I got from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python

For example, let's say in library.py I have a function with an unbound variable: def f(): return x. If I import library and set x in another file's scope, calling f() still won't dynamically recognize x (dynamic scoping)
