# make mutable attribute readonly in python

Tags: python, oop, attributes

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self._data = data
    
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data
```

Doing this prevents from assignments like `obj.data = [1, 2, 3]`, but it is still possible to modify it with `obj.data.append(10)` because lists are mutable. There's no problem for being able to modify it from `obj._data`, but I don't want it to be mutable from `obj.data`.

One thing I tried is making a copy of _data and then returning it

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self._data = data
    
    @property
    def data(self):
        copy = self._data[:]
        return copy
```

but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, are there any other alternative ways?

Comment: "best way" measured how?

Comment: You can use `tuple` instead of a `list`.

Comment: if you are using a list, it will be mutable. There is nothing you can do to change that. You can, of course, use something other than a list, or return a copy like you have in the question

Comment: @ScottHunter whatever is considered best practice

Comment: @AndrejKesely what if it's a dict?

Comment: @user316108 Then that's not possible, dict is mutable. You can make your own read only class mimicking dict for example.

Comment: We tend to avoid answering "best way" questions here, it's too subjective.

Comment: See: [How to create an immutable dictionary in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014262/how-to-create-an-immutable-dictionary-in-python) The list version is essentially the same. However, this does not address lists of lists or dicts being mutable or dictionary values of lists or dicts being mutable.