# Did I reinvent the wheel with this deduplicating function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I was looking for a `set()`-like method to deduplicate a list, except that the items figuring in the original list are not hashable (they are `dict`s).

I spent a while looking for something adequate, and I ended up writing this little function:

```
def deduplicate_list(lst, key):
    output = []
    keys = []
    for i in lst:
        if not i[key] in keys:
            output.append(i)
            keys.append(i[key])

    return output
```

Provided that a `key` is correctly given and is a `string`, this function does its job pretty well. Needless to say, if I learn about a built-in or a standard library module which allows the same functionality, I'll happily drop my little routine in favor of a more standard and robust choice.

Are you aware of such implementation?

**-- Note**

The following one-liner [found from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python),

```
[dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in l])]
```

while clever, won't work because I have to work with items as nested `dict`s.

**-- Example**

For clarity purposes, here is an example of using such a routine:

```
with_duplicates = [
    {
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "first-name": "John",
            "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
            "last-name": "Smith",
            "handle": "jsmith"
        },
        "id": "1234"
    },
    {
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "first-name": "John",
            "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
            "last-name": "Smith",
            "handle": "jsmith"
        },
        "id": "1234"
    }
]

without_duplicates = deduplicate_list(with_duplicates, key='id')
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample call of `deduplicate_list` on your list? (I can't see clearly what does it do) :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing a list of keys?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8714242/5741205) answer - it might help you to hash elements of your list

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau done

Comment: Do you want to maintain the order?

Comment: @schwobaseggl not at all

Comment: dict([(x[key],x) for x in with_duplicates]).values()

Answer (score 3):

You are picking only the first `dict` in your list for every distinct value for `key`. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is the built-in tool that can do that for you - sort and group by `key` and  take only the first from each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

def deduplicate(lst, key):
    fnc = lambda d: d.get(key)  # more robust than d[key]
    return [next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=fnc), key=fnc)]
```

Comment: nope, it gives: `TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()`

Comment: Hmm.. it worked for me and the exact list from your example. Python 2.7.11 ubuntu 14.04, I see. So maybe not in Python 3.x.

Comment: i'm using Python 3.5.1. It's `sorted(l)` - it gives me that error on Python 3

Comment: also you won't be able to compare the value of a certain key of the dicts

Comment: @DomTomCat Yeah, I was looking for a more generic solution. With a given key, it actually should get more robust. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714242/5741205) will help to solve a more generic problem - find unique elements not by a single attribute (`id` in your case), but if **any** nested attribute differs

The following code will return a list of indices of the unique elements

```
import copy

def make_hash(o):

  """
  Makes a hash from a dictionary, list, tuple or set to any level, that contains
  only other hashable types (including any lists, tuples, sets, and
  dictionaries).
  """

  if isinstance(o, (set, tuple, list)):

    return tuple([make_hash(e) for e in o])    

  elif not isinstance(o, dict):

    return hash(o)

  new_o = copy.deepcopy(o)
  for k, v in new_o.items():
    new_o[k] = make_hash(v)

  return hash(tuple(frozenset(sorted(new_o.items()))))

l = [
    {
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "first-name": "John",
            "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
            "last-name": "Smith",
            "handle": "jsmith"
        },
        "id": "1234"
    },
    {
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "first-name": "AAA",
            "email": "aaa.aaah@gmail.com",
            "last-name": "XXX",
            "handle": "jsmith"
        },
        "id": "1234"
    },
    {
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "first-name": "John",
            "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
            "last-name": "Smith",
            "handle": "jsmith"
        },
        "id": "1234"
    },
]

# get indicies of unique elements
In [254]: list({make_hash(x):i for i,x in enumerate(l)}.values())
Out[254]: [1, 2]
```

Comment: Do not use hashes to determine if two objects are the same. You always have the risk of hash collisions.

Comment: @Rob, doesn't the `set` implementation use hash (C or Cython implementation of this function) for generating "virtual" keys? And i guess it's a common practice to use `set(lst)` - for deduplicating lists...

Comment: `set` uses hashes indeed, but only to make the implementation faster. If two objects have the same hash but different values, they will still be separate in a `set`, but not in this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a short version which is based on the link to the answer, which you provided in the question:

```
key = "id"
deduplicated = [val for ind, val in enumerate(l)
                if val[key] not in [tmp[key] for tmp in l[ind + 1:]]]
print(deduplicated)
```

Note, this will take the last element of duplicates

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the value returned by the key is hashable. If this is always the case, then use this:

```
def deduplicate(lst, key):
    return list({item[key]: item for item in lst}.values())
```

If there are duplicates, only the last matching duplicate is retained.