# Cross-platform hash for a python dict?

Tags: python, hash

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884066/hashing-a-python-dictionary#5884123) describes several solutions for producing a hash value for a Python dictionary.

Some solutions work only with strings.  One works with non-strings, but uses the `hash` function, which is not cross-platform.

Is there a simple cross-platform hash of a Python dict?

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may be using the term "cross-platform" in a different meaning than it is customary - this may cause much confusion when reading your question.

Comment: No, unless you count copouts like `def dhash(d): return 0` or `if idonthavehandlingfor(thing): return 0 else: ...`.