# Repeatably hashing an arbitrary Python tuple

Tags: python, hash

I'm writing a specialised unit testing tool that needs to save the results of tests to be compared against in the future. Thus I need to be able to consistently map parameters that were passed to each test to the test result from running the test function with those parameters for each version. I was hoping there was a way to just hash the tuple and use that hash to name the files where I store the test results.

My first impulse was just to call `hash()` on the tuple of parameters, but of course that won't work since `hash` is randomized between interpreter instances now.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a way that works for whatever arbitrary elements that might be in the tuple (I guess restricting it to a mix of ints, floats, strings, and lists\tuples of those three would be okay). Any ideas?

I've thought of using the `repr` of the tuple or pickling it, but repr isn't guaranteed to produce byte-for-byte same output for same input, and I don't think pickling is either (is it?)

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884066/hashing-a-dictionary) already, but the answers are all based on that same assumption that doesn't hold anymore and don't really translate to this problem anyway, a lot of the discussion was about making the hash not depend on the order items come up and I do want the hash to depend on order.

Comment: I would pickle the tuple of the parameters _and_ the results into the same file whose name is the hashed tuple of parameters. That way, you should not need to worry about the randomization, because the original tuple is in the file.

Comment: @DYZ Right, I'm doing that too, but I need the tuple to be hashed repeatably to be able to find the file in the first place.

Comment: Is [disabling the hash randomization](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) acceptable?

Comment: @ShadowRanger That... would work, I suppose, but it's horribly inelegant and does technically mean someone can DOS my CI server with a specially crafted merge request.

Comment: If the parameters are all str-ingifiable, use a general purpose (eg. SHA) hash? Or crib something like Super7? :}

Comment: @Schilcote: So if this is a public facing server, that's a bad idea; the question made it sound like this was just for repeatable (assumed local) unit tests.

Comment: @user2864740 That _would_ work if we were only accepting numbers and strs, but arbitrary objects might not str to the same thing every time (and if repr is not overridden, by default they don't!)

Comment: For exactly your use-case, I'd avoid using the built-in `hash` function anyway as `hash(-1) == hash(-2)`, this also affects compound types: `hash(tuple('a', -1)) == hash(tuple('a', -2)`, etc. Unless you can guarantee that none of your test runs will have a parameter of -1 and another run of -2 on the same parameter, I'd avoid it. (`hash(-1) == hash(-2)` persists to at least Python version 3.8.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question fully, but will just give it a try.

Before you do the hash, just serialize the result to a JSON string, and do the hash computing on your JSON string.

```
params = (1, 3, 2)
hashlib.sha224(json.dumps(params)).hexdigest()
# '5f0f7a621e6f420002d54ee28b0c169b8112ef72d8a6b60e6a25171c'
```

If your params is a dictionary, use sort_keys=True to ensure your keys are sorted.

```
params = {'b': 123, 'c': 345}
hashlib.sha224(json.dumps(params, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
# '2e75966ce3f1185cbfb4eccc49d5552c08cfb7502a8765fe1dce9303'
```

Comment: Is the JSON result guaranteed to be the same every time?

Comment: @Schilcote For *lists* or *tuples* (and any stable primitives in such) it should be.

Comment: If you're serializing a tupple / list, then yes.

Comment: And for dictionaries, you can set `sort_keys` to `True`.

Comment: Oh, but this'll only work for things that the JSON library can handle natively... I guess that's still okay, but I was hoping for support for arbitrary objects.

Comment: @DYZ: A caution: `sort_keys` only works on Python 3 if the keys are homogeneous types (or otherwise have defined comparisons for all pairs of heterogeneous types, e.g. a mix of `int` and `float` is fine, but `int` and `str` is not). On Python 2, the fallback comparison allows it to (usually) work (though not necessarily repeatably, since the same-type fallback comparison is based on memory address, which isn't repeatable), but on Python 3 you'll just get a `TypeError`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yup, agree.

Comment: @schilcote, if you've already serialize the result into files, then I will suggest you do calculate a sha hash from your file and use that sha hash value as the name of the file.  Assuming the same test result will produce the same file (byte to byte comparison ).

Comment: @LiyingTang This poses the same problem of searchability: the OP will not be able to find the file that corresponds to a particular parameter set.

Comment: @DYZ I thought he / she only want to use the file name (aka a hash ) to do a quick comparison to test if the result match or not ... Or I am missing something here ?

Comment: @LiyingTang See the second comment to the original post.

Comment: @DYZ, ah got you. The name is the parameter only, not the actual result.

Answer (score 2):

One approach for simple tests would be to [disable the hash randomization entirely](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) by setting `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` in the environment that launches your script, e.g., in `bash`, doing:

```
export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
```

Comment: Note: This is only for the case where the tests are local; doing it on a public facing web service would expose you to denial of service attacks (which is what hash randomization was designed to protect you from).

Comment: Disabling the has randomization won't help the problem with `hash(-1) == hash(-2)` as all integers hash to themselves, except -1, which hashes to -2 (at least as recently as Python 3.8.2)

Comment: @mkoistinen: Sure? But that's a problem with hashing in general, and kind of irrelevant to this answer. Hash randomization is intended to remove the ability to craft colliding hashes; disabling it allows you to find colliding strings just as easily as you found colliding `int`s. `hash` of an `int` is going to potentially collide whether or not you disable it.

Comment: My response wasn't a criticism of your helpful post, nor did I downvote it, but rather my comment is a warning to others who attempt to use `hash()` similarly to the original question.