# How to hash a dictionary?

Tags: python

I wanted to know if you could hash a dictionary? Currently playing around with Blockchain! Here's the code I would like to hash:

```
def add_transactions():

    transaction = {

      "previous_block_hash": previous_block_hash() ,

      "index": increase_index(),

      "item": item(),

      "timestamp": datetime.datetime.now(),

      "sender": get_sender(),

      "receiver": get_receiver()

    }
```

Wanted to know the best way to apply `hashlib` to get 256 value
a4337bc45a8fc544c03f52dc550cd6e1e87021bc896588bd79e901e2

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hashing a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884066/hashing-a-dictionary)

Comment: Why not use some actual class to represent your data rather than a dictionary?

Answer (score 7):

Dictionary is unhashable data type in python. So you cannot hash a dictionary object. But, if you need to have some check sum you can serialize dictionary and then calculate its hash (just a workaround that can help).

For example using `jsonpickle` and `hashlib`:

```
import jsonpickle
import hashlib

dct = {"key": "value"}

serialized_dct = jsonpickle.encode(dct)

check_sum = hashlib.sha256(serialized_dct.encode('utf-8')).digest()

print(check_sum)
```

**UPD:**

Glich's code example is not precise and needs to be improved in this way:

```
import json
import hashlib

s = json.dumps({'test dict!': 42}).encode('utf-8')

print(hashlib.md5(s).digest())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hashlib` functions require a buffer (they work on raw data, not abstract objects whose data layout is an implementation detail of your Python interpreter). This means you'll have to *serialize* your data in some way first.

For example, you could convert your dict to JSON first using the `json` module.

```
>>> import json
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(json.dumps({'test dict!':42}))
<md5 HASH object @ 0000000002831058>
>>> _.digest()
'bg\xa3\xa5y)\x1f\xef\x8eP\xcd\xef\xfb7B\xb8'
```

Comment: It doesn't work in python 3.10.5. Throws `TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing`. See @artsiom-praneuski answer for the fix.