# Best way to uniquely identify a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a service in Python which processes some dictionaries. I wish to  find and store a unique identifier for one of these dictionaries (when a condition is met).

Then a different service can process a list of dictionaries.  This list contains the unique dictionary. If the unique identifier is found and verified, then the dictionary will be processed accordingly.

What is the best way to do achieve this. I thought maybe adding a new field to the dictionary something like

```
my_dict["unique_dict"] = True
```

but is there a better way?

Comment: would `id(my_dict)` do what you need?

Comment: no cause I dont want to pass any reference to the object. They are completely different services consuming the same data independently.

Comment: The answer is probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438471/2449857

Comment: @JackDeeth yeah I found a similar solution somewhere else, same idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way. One could to hash the dictionary like this for example:

```
import hashlib
import json

hasher = hashlib.sha1()
unhashed = {
    "msg": "blablabla",
    "measurements": [23, 567, 90],
    "calculation": 70.34,
}
encoded = json.dumps(unhashed, sort_keys=True).encode()
hasher.update(encoded)
hashed = hasher.hexdigest()
print(hashed)
```

and then store that hashed number in Redis, for example, or in a database or in cache or something.

Then in the second service the list of dictionaries will be hashed one by one. If one is found to have a hashed value that matches the stored value, it will then be processed accordingly.

Comment: There's a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438471/2449857) using an MD5 hash.