# Unhashable type dict while deduping a nested dictionary that has duplicate inner dictionaries for multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dictionary, 'solutions', that holds for each key another nested dictionary as its value. This inner dict is a dictionary that holds various transportation details which was generated programmatically in a specific sequence. This sequence needs to be preserved. An example of a couple of entries of 'solutions' are:

```
{'Eval-49998': {'N1': {('N2', 'RD', 'C7'): [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1]}, 
                'N2': {('N3', 'AR', 'C5'): [63, 0.5, 11.1, 158.25]}, 
                'N3': {('N4', 'RD', 'C7'): [15.0, 0.5, 0.33, 42.9]}, 
                'Cost': 159.31, 'Distance': 642.33, 
                'Time': 12.18, 'Total Rewards': -151.38}, 
 'Eval-49999': {'N1': {('N2', 'RD', 'C7'): [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1]}, 
                'N2': {('N3', 'AR', 'C5'): [63, 0.5, 11.1, 158.25]}, 
                'N3': {('N4', 'RD', 'C7'): [15.0, 0.5, 0.33, 42.9]}, 
                'Cost': 159.31, 'Distance': 642.33, 
                'Time': 12.18, 'Total Rewards': -151.38}}
```

As you can see both Eval-49998 and Eval-49999 have same entries for their respective values (the inner dicts).

There are 50000 entries in solutions dictionary and much of these are duplicate. I want to remove the duplicate entries leaving only the first uniques key,value pair found for each unique entry. So, if the above example were the entire dictionary, I would want to dedup 'solutions' to retain only:

```
{'Eval-49998': {'N1': {('N2', 'RD', 'C7'): [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1]}, 
                'N2': {('N3', 'AR', 'C5'): [63, 0.5, 11.1, 158.25]}, 
                'N3': {('N4', 'RD', 'C7'): [15.0, 0.5, 0.33, 42.9]}, 
                'Cost': 159.31, 'Distance': 642.33,  
                'Time': 12.18, 'Total Rewards': -151.38}}
```

'solutions' was declared as dict() and was populated via code logic. Then I call the deduping method on it as such, sort the result, and print the values.

```
solutions = dedupeSolutions(solutions)
sorted_rewards = sorted(solutions.keys(), key=lambda x: solutions[x]['Total Rewards'])
for i in sorted_rewards:
    print(i, ": ", solutions[i])
```

Elsewhere I have defined dedupeSolutions as:

```
def dedupeSolutions(the_solution):
    u = set()
    dedupedSolutions = dict()
    for k in the_solution.items():
        print(k)
        if k[1] not in u:
            u.add(k[1])
            dedupedSolutions[k[0]] = k[1]
    return dedupedSolutions
```

When I execute the code, the print statement output is as follows:

```
('Eval-0', {'N1': {('N2', 'RD', 'C7'): [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1]}, 
            'N2': {('N5', 'AR', 'C3'): [844.0, 0.5, 16.1, 192.25]}, 
            'N5': {(N4', 'RD', 'C7'): [291.0, 0.5, 83.0, 91.94]}, 
            'Cost': 2841.35, 
            'Distance': 1122.33, 
            'Time': 99.85, 
            'Total Rewards': -183.35})
```

But then it throws up following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tapas/PycharmProjects/Q-Learn/routing.py", line 330, in <module>
    solutions = dedupeSolutions(solutions)
  File "/Users/tapas/PycharmProjects/Q-Learn/routing.py", line 205, in dedupeSolutions
    if k[1] not in u:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Can anyone please help showing me the light here?

Comment: do these: `'N1': {('N2', 'RD', 'C7'): [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1]}` actually have to be dicts?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes; what are your thought behind the ask?

Comment: That it ould just be a list of tuples.  Or just a tuple. *Why* must it be a dictionary? There is only one key-value pair

Comment: While the last three key-value pairs describe the overall performance of the specific evaluation cycle - in this case defined by Eval-0, the first three define the route in sequence. N1 -> N2 -> N5 -> N4. Each segment is a selection of a specific mode of transport and via a specific carrier. The corresponding values in [...] pertains to various performances for the selected route, mode, and carrier. I thought dict is the easiest representation for this.

Comment: Im sorry, that doesn't answer why `{('N2', 'RD', 'C7'): [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1]}` is a dict. Again, it has a *single key value pair*. Why not just `(('N2', 'RD', 'C7'), [27.33, 0.5, 0.75, 78.1])`?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the set is trying to hash the dictionary you are passing in (this is how the set checks for equality) and raising an error because dict is not hashable.

I recommend converting the dict into a string like mentioned here [Hashing a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884066/hashing-a-dictionary) (json dump seems reasonable) and then doing whatever add-to-set or check-if-in-set operations you want on that.

Comment: Ah! got it. But in that case, rather than hashing,  can I simply change the set() to [] for u and append to the list. Any advantages or disadvantage between the approaches? Also are there any other better approach to achieve the same goal of removing duplicate values (of nested dict structure) from a dict?

Comment: @user1931485 yes, that'll work just fine although the performance could be an issue if you consistently have more than 49998+

Comment: @user1931485 a list will aboslutely be sub-optimal

Answer (score 0):

Following @jdkramhoft's clue and my follow up question, I went ahead and tried the following which did the trick. I still will love to know if there is a better and simpler way to do the job.

```
def dedupeDict(the_solution):
u = []
dedupedSolutions = dict()
for k in the_solution.items():
    if k[1] not in u:
        u.append(k[1])
        dedupedSolutions[k[0]] = k[1]
return dedupedSolutions
```

Comment: a *better* way is not to use `dict` objects, which are unhashable, and use some hashable object (e.g. some custom class you create)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How can I preserve the order / sequence in that case? May you provide an example please?